How do I get Query to accept a value/variable in my predicate
I am trying figure out how to get my query to accept a variable in the filter.    Here is my code in my view:
let tripTimestamp = convertToDateISO8601(from: "2024-03-13T14:26:45Z")

@Query(filter: #Predicate<TripSummariesSD> {$0.originationTimestamp = tripTimestamp}, sort: [SortDescriptor(\TripSummariesSD.originationTimestamp)] )

func convertToDateISO8601(from dateString: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" // ISO 8601 format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) // Set the timezone to UTC

    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
}

I keep getting the error 'Instance member 'tripTimestamp' cannot be used on type 'XtripView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?'

Does this answer your question? SwiftData query with dynamic properties in a View

The basic problem is that you can’t access the property tripTimestamp at the top level in your view, you need to be inside an init, function, etc
